# Why isn't my SQL datamart any faster than my raw production database query?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-design, query-optimization, datamart

I have a large query that joins numerous tables and runs a bunch of calculations to retrieve YoY Sales Data from 2020 to date. When I run the full query from our production database it takes about 40 seconds to execute and returns about 700,000 records. This report contains line item invoice/credit memo data by customer for all invoice/CM documents, so as a view it has a lot of powerful metrics to work off of. My goal is to optimize the time it takes to run the query so I can use the query as a view to source BI reports off of. (Not Power BI--we use another BI tool called Dashboard Fox.)

I insert all of the records into a datamart so that SQL can pull the hard-coded values and not have to process any joins or calculations. This should help immensely with performance and I should in theory be able to pull the datamart table in a matter of seconds. But the datamart table still takes 30 seconds to return a `SELECT *` query. I've looked at the execution plan and can confirm that all it's doing is a table scan, whereas the original production query execution plan was complex.

I was expecting much more improvement from the production database view.

Is it normal for 700,000 records to take 30 seconds to return?

How can I pull this data faster for dynamic reporting solutions?

Comment: You've mad the assumption the duration is due to query execution time but it could be network or client processing time. Does the query take 30 seconds when run from SSMS or is that from your BI tool?

Comment: Please ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question. Debug questions require a [mre]. [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/3404097) [ask] [Help]

Comment: Hey @DanGuzman - that 30 seconds is running SELECT * from the newly made table. The original query is kind of irrelevant, as I'm just wondering why selecting the records from the new table is so inefficient....

Comment: What tool did you use to execute the `SELECT *` query? Try running it from SSMS with the "Discard results after execution" option (main menu from Query window: Query-->Options-->Results) to measure the time without rendering.

Comment: There's no wierd SQL magic that makes it super-fast to retrieve almost a megarow from a table, serialize it, send it over the client<->server connection to your app, deserialize it, and process it. This is true even if the query involved has a trivial execution plan like "scan the whole table".  If you must handle every row, that is you don't have a `WHERE` clause, you *could* dump your data into an ordinary flat file and have your analytics read the file, instead of using a denormalized table.

Answer (score 1):

Try a query that doesn't return 700,000 rows to the client, like a GROUP BY query that returns fewer rows. And store the table as a [clustered columnstore](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/indexes/columnstore-indexes-overview?view=sql-server-ver16) which provide excellent compression and super-fast scanning.

Comment: I'll try the clustered column store, but I need to return all 700,00 rows... otherwise we're missing data for our insights.